# How to make this PHP snippet work without warning?

Tags: php, warnings

The code is short,but **complete**:

```
function process($obj)
{
    if(empty($obj))return 1;
    return 2;
}


echo process($arr['nosuchkey']);
```

As we all know, calling `empty($arr['nosuchkey'])` will never report warnings.

But `process($arr['nosuchkey'])` will report a notice.

Is there a workaround without disabling warnings; say, by syntax?

Comment: What is the warning msg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [error control operator @](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) but that will suppress a lot more than just notices.

```
echo @process($arr['nosuchkey']);
```

You would be better off checking before the function call:

```
if (array_key_exists('nosuchkey', $arr))
    echo process($arr['nosuchkey']);
```

Or passing the key separately

```
echo process($arr, 'nosuchkey');
```

Be sure you know the difference between [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty), [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) and [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) - they catch a lot of people out.

Comment: Checking before the function will render function absolutely useless

Comment: Yes, please avoid the @ operator.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
 function process(&$obj)
```

Im not sure if it will work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
function process($obj, $index = null) {
    if(is_array($obj))
    {
         if(!array_key_exists($index, $obj))
             return 1;
         else
             return 2;
    }

    if(empty($obj)) 
        return 1;

    return 2;

}
```

Please don't hide warnings with @ whenever possible.